# Edit, drag and drop boxes on webpage and save contents and position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking for a starting point as to how to achieve a simple webpage with drag and drop boxes. The boxes should be editable (either text content or some html/image upload functionality).

Any visitor to the site should be able to move boxes around, change the contents and then save the results (or ideally they don't even need to click a save button).

Where should I be starting to achieve this? The hardest part I envisage is how to 'save' to the server and then serve the edited version of the page? I don't know how to use SQL, and have limited knowledge of server side script.

I am not looking for a full solution here, just some pointers please!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just providing you the template to start with.
Below code will allow you to move div and also edit text.

```js
var makeMove;
  x0=0;
  y0=0;
  function move(e){
   if(makeMove){
    x1 = e.clientX;
    y1 = e.clientY;
    cx=x0+x1-x;
    cy=y0+y1-y;
    
    document.getElementById("dragableForm").style.left = cx +"px";
    document.getElementById("dragableForm").style.top = cy +"px";
    e.preventDefault();
   }
  }
  function mouseUp(e){
   makeMove=false;
   x0=cx;
   y0=cy;
  }
  function mouseDown(e){
   makeMove=true;
   x = e.clientX;
   y = e.clientY;
  }
```

```css
.container{
   width: 600px;
   height: 500px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
  #dragableForm{
   border:1px solid black;
   position:relative;
  }
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="container" onmousemove="move(event)" onmouseup="mouseUp(event)" onmousedown="mouseDown(event)">
  <div id="dragableForm" style="background-color: #00ff00;padding:10px;width:70%">
   <textarea  rows="4" cols="50">
    your input here
   </textarea>
   <button>save</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```